# Geonetwork ISO 19110 multilingual editing

Tags: geonetwork

I have not seen it in the documentation, but from user conferences I have seen that GeoNetwork supports multilingual editing for ISO 19110 (https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/gfoss-day-2012-geonetwork-presentation) when editing feature catalogs.

However I have not seen any example or template, and I have not been able to add multilingual properties in ISO 19110 metadata.

Anyone has any experience on that?